# Change background from white to transparent in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I'm importing SVGs with imagick using this syntax

```
$graphic = new Imagick($this->img);
```

The problem is this image is imported with a white background. How can I change the white background to a transparent one, or make imagick keep then transparent background when importing the SVG.

Comment: were you able to get your php code working to get the svg into transparent png background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you with imagick. However, I know that an SVG with a transparent background gets converted to a PDF with transparent background if I use this ImageMagick ClI command:

```
convert -background none some.svg some.pdf
```

and if I use

```
convert -background gray some.svg some.pdf
```

the PDF indeed has a gray background.